# Как заставить скрипт работать на нужной странице?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет!

Есть сайт **https://pcpartpicker.com/products/<категория товаров>**, где мне не нравилось отображение картинок товаров, т.к. они были очень маленькими.

Допустим мы смотрим **https://pcpartpicker.com/products/headphones**. С помощью расширения для Chrome я дополнил CSS страницы и картинки стали больше. Но вот беда - разрешение у них маленькое, выглядит некрасиво. К счастью у каждого товара есть бОльшая версия этой картинки и адрес картинки отличается таким образом: **<ссылка>256p.jpg** у меньшего и **<ссылка>1600.jpg** у большего.

Я написал скрипт, который находит в коде все подобные адреса, отрезает у них последние 8 символов, приклеивает нужно мне окончание и вставляет адрес обратно в код страницы. Тестирование скрипта на части кода страницы прошло успешно, **но** на самом сайте скрипт (запускаю с помощью расширения **User JavaScript and CSS**) не выполняется.
Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону смотреть и что может быть причиной проблемы.

Вот сам скрипт:

```
let imglinks = document.querySelectorAll('img');
  
  for (let elem of imglinks) {
    let link=elem.src;
    let linkstr = String(link);
    let newlink=linkstr.substr(0, linkstr.length-8);
    newlink +="1600.jpg"
    //elem.src = newlink;
    elem.setAttribute("src", newlink);
  }
```

Comment: Только что заметил, что скрипт работает и на сайте, но как раз со всеми картинками кроме нужных :(

Comment: Подождите, вы хотите сделать это изменение для всех пользователей, или только для себя?

Comment: Если вы хотите сделать изменение для всех пользователей, то это решение явно не подходит.

Comment: Для себя, я не имею отношения к этому сайту

Comment: [Вообще не работает](https://i.imgur.com/zIZfJwU.png "скриншот ошибок")

Comment: @Petəíŕd-CSC  Не совсем понял, что вы хотели сказать.
Если например заменить селектор в скрипте на "img", то [работает, но на всех картинках кроме нужных](https://imgur.com/a/h5jFgAI)

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл такое решение на странице с категорией `headphones`, которую Вы использовали как пример.

Используя чистый `css` и дополнение для браузера `chrome`, которое вы выбрали

```css
.productList--detailed .tr__product .td__imageWrapper{
    height: auto !important;
    width: auto !important;
}

table.productList--detailed tr td.td__name a .td__image{
    height: 500px; // Тут изменить значения на нужные Вам
    width: 500px;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы меня неверно поняли, вы увеличили картинки (кстати ваш код у меня не так как у вас работает), это я умею, а я хочу в автоматическом режиме менять картинки с помощью замены ссылок на заранее неизвестные в src. Это средствами CSS сделать нельзя как я понимаю, поэтому прошу помочь со скриптом